# restart docker containers after reboot

Tags: docker

I have been trying to make docker containers restart after reboot. I am using `--restart unless-stopped`
 option. Container starts after reboot but I have to be logged in to my remote machine. I am running docker on my remote machine.

```
docker run --restart unless-stopped -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --net sp-example-net -p 8080:8080 sp
```

Answer (score 1):

Docker has restart policies such as --restart=always that will handle this. This is also available in the compose.yml config file as restart: always.

Comment: It should work can you please share some more details. Does your docker start at system boot?